# show position of highest and lowest value on a list without using any methods Python

Tags: python

hello I need to create a list that will show the position where it has the highest and lowest value typed by the user but without using any methods.

I already did half of it but when it comes to show the position I'm not sure how to do this without using a function. Any ideas?

```
listone = [0] * 10

for c in range (0, 10):

    listone[c] = (int(input('Type 10 values: ')))

    if c == 0:

        high = low = listone[c]

    else:
        if listone[c] > high:
            high = listone[c]
        if listone[c] < low:
            low = listone[c]


print(f'The highest value typed was  {high} and the lowest  '
      f'was  {low}')
```

Comment: Can you also tell us why you need that? It may be an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: university asked some exercises that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use python's inbuilt function for returning the index, then either you manually put a for loop in its place, or put that for loop in a user-defined function for modularity's sake, just like I have.

```
listone = [0] * 10
feed_in = [23, 43, 1, 11, 90, 98, 23, 32, 43, 54] # Im sparing myself the effort of manually inputting
for c in range (0, 10):
    # listone[c] = (int(input('Type 10 values: ')))
    listone[c] = feed_in[c]
    if c == 0:
        high = low = listone[c]
    else:
        if listone[c] > high:
            high = listone[c]
        if listone[c] < low:
            low = listone[c]

def find_index(array, element):
    for iters in range(len(array)):
        if array[iters] == element:
            return iters

print(f'The highest value typed was at {find_index(listone, high)} and the lowest was {find_index(listone, low)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import random

random_numbers = random.sample(range(0, 100), 10)

highest_score = 0

for index, value in enumerate(random_numbers):
    if value > highest_score:
        highest_score = value
        highest_index = index

print(highest_index, highest_score)
print(random_numbers)
```